# How do I delete a folder that another process has open?

Tags: delphi

I created two services. I want to delete a folder, but that folder is used by my first service. When I execute the first service after that I execute the second service it works fine. But when I try to execute both service at the same time it does not work properly.

Comment: (-1) Please ask a proper question, it is not possible to find out what you want to do right now. Also, I'll take the liberty of reducing the number of question marks in your question :)

Comment: @Pekka: Maybe the question marks were part of the question's subject? (kind of file system placeholders). ;-)

Comment: sir..actually i created two services..i want to delete the folder..but that folder is using by my first service..when i execute first service after that i execute second service its works fine...but when i try to execute both service at a time it does not work properly...whts the issue..can u tell me....

Comment: Voted for reopen, since now the question is more clear. I also copied Prakash' comment into the original message, and corrected interpunction a bit.

Comment: @Prakash Ranjan: Folder can be "used" by the service in the following ways: 1. You hold some files in this folder open, in which case figure out which ones and close them. 2. You have this folder set as a current folder, in which case SetCurrentDir() to a different folder.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the question should have been "What in the application could prevent folder from deletion by other applications".

Possibilities are:

1. Your service opens some file in that folder and does not close it. Check all files that you are opening in the service, and close the ones which are in that folder.
   How files are closed depends on how they were opened. If you used CreateFile(), then close with CloseHandle(). If it was TFileStream, then just Destroy it.
2. Your service has that folder set as the current directory. Choose other directory as a current with SetCurrentDir.

Comment: And the answer to the question in the title then would be: You cannot, at least not under Windows. (e.g. Linux allows to delete files and folders that are in use which can be annoying if you are not used to it.)

Answer (score 1):

you cannot delete it unless, you can tell the other service by sending message to stop using the folder(or its content) before deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

If first service is launched before second service then you can delete folder but if both services are launched together then you can't delete folder.

Only difference is you allowed time for first service to finish working with the folder.

Things to consider:

If your first service is using the folder then you won't be able to delete it until your service closes connection with that folder like already mentioned.