# How to delete the folder in which the application (self) is running?

Tags: delphi

From an application I want to delete a folder. The problem is that the folder also contains that application. So, as long as the application is running the folder is locked. How can I delete that folder?

The first thought was to make a copy of that application in 'Temp' and run it from there. This way it it will release the folder. Not a very elegant solution though....

The OS is Win7 but it should work on all from Win2K up to Win 8.
The goal is to let the application to self-uninstall (clean up its folder, then self delete).

---

Somebody suggested that if I do this in my app it will work. It doesn't.

> SetCurrentDir(SomeOtherFolder);

Comment: As [dummzeuch said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014268/how-do-i-delete-a-folder-that-another-process-has-open#comment4312030_4014883), guessing this may not be possible to do. What is your ultimate goal here?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/4014268

Comment: You can't do this as long as your application is running. If you need the application to be untouched on the screen while the folder it is running from is being deleted, then you are out of luck. If on the other hand you just want to shut everything down and get rid of the exe and folder it is running in, then that should be doable. I would create a small cleanup app, which is copied to a temp folder, pretty similarly to what you are suggesting. Then run the cleanup app from your main app and quit. The cleanup app then deletes everything and exits.

Comment: If you delete the executable file, how will the OS page in the module?

Comment: The question "how to delete a folder on the next OS load" would be more interesting.

Comment: @user246408 that would be a different question

Comment: What OS and filesystem are you using?

Comment: I did the thing with the TEMP copy. Solved with 8 lines of code :)

Comment: We need just one vote to reopen it :)

Comment: The temp copy is the thing that you said you don't want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, the executable file is locked while the process executes in such a way that the file cannot be deleted. So you will need to wait until the process has stopped executing before you can delete the executable file.

There are two options that appear to me to be viable:

1. Use another process to perform the deletion. That process can wait until the target process has stopped and then perform deletion.
2. Use MoveFileEx passing the MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT flag and nil for the destination.

Comment: Thanks David. I will try the second thing. Accepted.